# Simplifying trigonometric identity: $(\cos^4x-\sin^4x) = 2\sin^2x-1$

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify $$ \left(\cos^4x-\sin^4x\right) = 2\sin^2x-1 $$

But how can anyone show why this is true?

I ended with $ \sin^2x-\cos^2x $.

Comment: Maybe it is the same thing ?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given equation is merely conditionally true, but becomes an identity once a negative sign inserted in front:

\begin{align}&-\left(\cos^4x-\sin^4x\right)
\\\equiv&\sin^4x-(1-\sin^2x)^2
\\\equiv&2\sin^2x-1\end{align}

Comment: Thanks I don't understand why that's true now I knew it thanks ryang

Comment: @Blueemerald For future reference, verify that the given equation is true for all $x$ by [checking that the graph of LHS minus RHS identically equals $0$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8xbhvj7oat).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Factor $\cos^4 x - \sin^4 x$ into two similar terms, i.e. $$(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)$$  What do you notice with this factorization?  And how can you resolve it?

Comment: The identity is false, as you can see by substituting $0$ for $x$.

Comment: I've updated my post and removed the "identity" language.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is false.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos ^{4} x-\sin ^{4} x &=\left(\cos ^{2} x+\sin ^{2} x\right)\left(\cos ^{2} x-\sin ^{2} x\right) \\
&=\cos ^{2} x-\sin ^{2} x \\
&=1-\sin ^{2} x-\sin ^{2} x \\
&=1-2 \sin ^{2} x
\end{aligned}
$$